# java matrix 0's and 1's

Tags: java, matrix, methods

Hey guys so this is my homework question: Write a method that displays an n by n matrix in a dialog box using the following header:
**public static void printMatrix(int n)**

Each element in the matrix is 0 or 1, which is generated randomly.
A 3 by 3 matrix may look like this:

0 1 0

0 0 0

1 1 1

So far, I could easily print out my problem in a scanner, however I'm not sure how to do it in a dialog box.

At the moment I'm getting the error:
**error: 'void' type not allowed here JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, printMatrix(n));
1 error**

I know that it's a void, and can't be returned however, my assignment requires the method to be void. My real question is how would I print it in the method then? I've been working on this problem for 4 hours and it's really frustrating me.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    // Main method
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Prompt user to enter numbers
        String stringInteger = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a integer n to determine the size of matrix: ", "Size of Matrix Input", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        // Convert string to integer
        int n = Integer.parseInt(stringInteger);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, printMatrix(n));
    }   

    // Generate and display random 0's and 1's accordingly
    public static void printMatrix(int n)
    {
        // Row depending on n times
        for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
        {
            // Column depending on n times
            for (int col = 0; col < n; col++)
            {
                String randomN = ((int)(Math.random() * 2)+ " ");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to include my code: [link](http://ideone.com/nw6s6e)

Comment: Please consider adding your code to your question.

Comment: You have to call the message dialog in the method `printMatrix()` as long as you are not allowed to change the methods signature

Comment: The response type of your method is void so you cannot pass the method as a parameter

Comment: Please don't link to your code on an off-site resource, include your code in the question itself. I've pasted it for you here.

Comment: agi, can you explain a bit more about the printMatrix(), I'm not quite understanding what you're trying to say

Comment: "so this is my homework"... well, at least he's honest! ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code will do everything inside your printMatrix();

```
   class DialogPrint
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            // Prompt user to enter numbers
             String stringInteger = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a integer n to determine the size of matrix: ", "Size of Matrix Input", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            // Convert string to integer
            int n = Integer.parseInt(stringInteger);
            printMatrix(n);
        }   

        // Generate and display random 0's and 1's accordingly
        public static void printMatrix(int n)
        {
            // Row depending on n times



            String sb="";


            for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
            {
                // Column depending on n times
                for (int col = 0; col < n; col++)
                {
                    String randomN = ((int)(Math.random() * 2)+ " ");
                    sb+=randomN;
                }
                sb+="\n";
            }

            System.out.print(sb);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb);

        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but once again my method has to be public static void printMatrix(int n)

Comment: I have added here another code block which will follow everything you required. static void method of printMatrix

Comment: @Flinze If you can't use StringBuilder then you can just use String global variable.public static void printMatrix(int n)
    {
        // Row depending on n times
     String sb="";
     
        for (int row = 0; row < n; row++)
        {
            // Column depending on n times
            for (int col = 0; col < n; col++)
            {
                String randomN = ((int)(Math.random() * 2)+ " ");
                sb+=randomN;
            }
            sb+="\n";
        }

        sbglobal=sb;
    }

Comment: It looks like I'm actually suppose to print using a dialog box within public static void printMatrix(int n), I'm not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: You can just move everything from main function to this function and call this function only from main. That will do the same work and you don't need to create global variable as well. I also have added another chunk of code as your requirement.@Flinze

Comment: if you need to call printMatrix(int n) then just move this two line to man function and call the printMatrix(n).                                                        String stringInteger = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a integer n to determine the size of matrix: ", "Size of Matrix Input", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        // Convert string to integer
        int n = Integer.parseInt(stringInteger);

Comment: What's dialog print? Once again, I was told I can print from the printMatrix method using JOptionPane. And I'm not able to use StringBuilder.

Comment: Correct, though is it possible to move    String stringInteger = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a integer n to determine the size of matrix: ", "Size of Matrix Input", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        // Convert string to integer
        int n = Integer.parseInt(stringInteger);

        String sb=""; 
back into the main method?

Comment: And sorry for the confusion, but it only needs to be displayed in as JOptionPane, not on scanner.

Comment: yes, off course, I have edited once more. You can see, I have moved that part to main method and called printMatrix(n) from there.

Comment: @Flinze, if you don't want to print in console, just remove the extra print inside printMatrix method. It's printing both in JOptionPane and also in console.

Comment: Thanks, though is there a way to do this without using a string? It's good so far, and I'm able to use it, however it would be best without using String.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are being asked to `print`. Also, I would prefer [`Random.nextBoolean()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBoolean--) for generating the character. Loop and call `System.out.print`. Something like,

```
public static void printMatrix(int n) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.print(rand.nextBoolean() ? "1 " : "0 ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printMatrix(3);
}
```

If you *really* want to use a [`JOptionPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) you might use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to construct the matrix and *then* display it. Something like,

```
public static void printMatrix(int n) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            sb.append(rand.nextBoolean() ? "1 " : "0 ");
        }
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString());
}
```

But a `void` method doesn't return anything, so you can't print the result of a `void` method in the caller.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I have to print everything on the dialog box. This is for a class in school, and we haven't learned StringBuilder, so we can't apply that into our code.

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification done to your method I am providing screenshot of output.

```
private static Object printMatrix(int n) {
        // Column depending on n times
        String randomN[][] = new String[n][n];
        for(int row = 0 ;row<n;row++)
        {
              for (int col = 0; col < n; col++)
                 {
                      randomN[row][col] = ((int)(Math.random() * 2)+ " ");
                 }
        }
        String s = Arrays.deepToString(randomN).replace("], ", "\n").replaceAll(",|\\[|\\]", "");
        return s;
    }
```

[image]

Hope you found my code helpful cheers happy coding.